# Horror Comic From the 80's

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror

I've been trying to find this comic for years, it was sold at Fred Meyers in
the early 80's.  It had a very Bruce Jones style, very dark.  Here is what I remember:

- The plot follows 2 mutant creatures from the sea who both lose their mates due to nuclear
  waste/ testing. One is a human type Gill-Man, the other is a giant octopus / lovecraft type
  creature, both can speak english.
- The humanoid creature comes to a city near the ocean to warn the locals the octopus one is going to attack.  It centers on some kid who is telepathic or psionic,
  ; the giant octopus guy shows up at a pier and eats a man eating squid or octopus at a stand.  He attacks full-on and somehow gets fixated on this telepathic kid.

That's about all I remember.  It was in color, and isn't from Twisted Tales, Tales of Terror, etc.  I also can't remember if it was Comico, Aircel, or some lesser-known publisher.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: was it a one-off, or a series?

Comment: I remember least of all the cover, I would say it was part of a series but not certain about that. Possibly anthology style.